# SQL Server float data type understanding

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

After I insert a value `(0.12346789123456789123456789)` for example in the table that has a float type column, I query and get back `0.1234567891234568` which contains `17` digits. I have 3 questions

1. How can I back track the binary representation of the input and output ? The document says it uses 53 bits as default. I am using SQL Server Management Studio and I don't know how to specify `n` value during declaration of my column type.
2. The number `17` isn't included in the document, I wish to know where it comes from.
3. In Big or Little Endian systems, I'd like to know how such an input is treated and translated into the output at the low-level byte system. If anyone knows an explanation, I would be thankful.

Comment: `float` is approximate. If you want something more accurate use `numeric`

Comment: Is numeric almost the same as decimal ?

Comment: Yes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @i float = 0.1234567890123456789123456789
SELECT @i

0.123456789012346
```

That has 15 digits; and

> Note that first `0` is not counted.

```
DECLARE @i float = 123456.1234567890123456789123456789
SELECT @i

123456.123456789
```

Also has 15 digits.

That is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) that Precision is 15 digits