# SQL Server float data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I started this thread [SQL Server float data type understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098903/sql-server-float-data-type-understanding)

And the following question is partially related to it, so I bring it up back here.

Documents and SQL Server users say that `float(8 bytes)` and `real(4 bytes)` data types are for approximate use only. I can see that via use of SQL Server Management Studio and some simple queries like

```
declare @f float=0.000123456789123456789;
select @f;
```

where the output becomes `0.000123456789123457` (auto round-off error) as the precision is set to `15` non-zero digits and after the decimal point.

I think the output by SQLServer Management Studio is implementation defined. Because the byte series fed into the system is transformed into a long bit integer then cast into a `float` type of the same precision depending upon the language being used to implement the system and the casting functions. If the main cause lies right at this point then I think the approximation issue can be fixed. That is to reprogram the functions with data streaming to get back the exact values as previously input.

However, I still wish to learn what other particular examples you know about that can exhibit their approximate error symptoms ?

I still do have another question mentioned also in my previous thread about the byte order and its transformation of float and real data type when it is being processed in either big and little endian systems. If someone could offer me some ideas, it would be really awesome. 
My take on this is that `float` is fixed on `little endian`, `real` is not an exception because they are different only in the storage. Their functions are totally the same. Yet confirmation from experts over this is badly needed.

Comment: I'm not sure how you conclude that the output is implementation defined. Or why you think that a `float` is not an IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point number, for that matter.

Comment: I mean it is not only 15, it can be much longer.

Comment: **Do not** use SSMS to try to prove things. It is displaying a *user friendly* representation of the data (see [Full precision output of floating point types in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099575/full-precision-output-of-floating-point-types-in-sql-server-management-studio) for example)

Comment: I don't fully understand this question. Are you simply interested in any examples where one could observe floating-point inaccuracies? If so, here's one: `SELECT 1.0 / 9.0 * 9.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take this as an example:

```
DECLARE @a float = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000001
DECLARE @b float = 98749946543
DECLARE @c float = 12345679491

SELECT @a * (@b * @c) as [a(bc)], (@a * @b) * @c as [(ab)c]

--Check
IF ((SELECT @a * (@b * @c)) <> (SELECT (@a * @b) * @c))
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Match!'
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Mismatch!'
END
```

Both expressions are mathematical the same. But float will fail on this.

Just as an evidence, the same using decimal:

```
DECLARE @a decimal(38,37) = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000001
DECLARE @b decimal(38,27) = 98749946543
DECLARE @c decimal(38,27) = 12345679491

SELECT @a * (@b * @c) as [a(bc)], (@a * @b) * @c as [(ab)c]

--Check
IF ((SELECT @a * (@b * @c)) <> (SELECT (@a * @b) * @c))
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Match!'
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Mismatch!'
END
```

Comment: Awesome, I love this.

Comment: By the way, I've just added the decimal example to it. It will match.